# php class not found from composer package

Tags: php, class, namespaces, require

I installed this package `composer require konekt/pdf-invoice` but standard `use` is not finding the class when its being called.

And then in my script I am using:

```
<?php
include "includes/basics.php" ;
use Konekt\PdfInvoice\InvoicePrinter;


function genPDF($id) {
  $invoice = new InvoicePrinter();
  ...
  ...
}
?>
```

And its generating the error:
`PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Konekt\PdfInvoice\InvoicePrinter' not found in wBilling.php:511`

In my `/home/userID/php/vendor/konekt/pdf-invoice` exists and from what I can tell the composer.json file is properly defined

```
{
    "name": "konekt/pdf-invoice",
    "description": "Library to generate PDF invoices",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "keywords": ["invoice", "pdf", "konekt", "artkonekt"],
    "support": {
        "source": "https://github.com/artkonekt/pdf-invoice"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Attila Fulop",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/fulopattila122"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "setasign/fpdf": "~1.8.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Konekt\\PdfInvoice\\": "src/" }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Konekt\\PdfInvoice\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.5-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `genPDF` `wBilling.php:511`?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto  Line 511 is the `$invoice = new InvoicePrinter();` line in the genPDF function.

Comment: You use `PdfInvoice`, but the error `PDfInvoice`. #curious

Comment: I must have typo'd that.  Correcting the OP now.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto - I just figured it out.  I need to load the `autoloder.php` file before all the namespaces were loaded.  `require '/home/userID/php/vendor/autoload.php'` ;  After that, the class was found.  Is there away to have composer namespaces auto added so I don't need to do the `require` statement every script?

Comment: Oh i see. It based on your structure. For more info https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md